# Tabcmd worksheet publish error

Tags: tableau-api

I was trying to publish a tableau work sheet using tabcmd.exe utility but getting an error.

```
*** 411 "Length Required"
```

The tabcmd log file has the follwoing entries.

```
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:42,437: ====>> Starting Tabcmd 8.0 at Tue Nov 05 05:11:42 UTC 2013 <<====  
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:42,437: Build 8000.13.1001.1930  
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:45,195: run as: tabcmd publish "tabcmd_publish.twbx" -n "tabcmd_publish" -r "Default" --db-user "username" --db-password "password" -o --no-certcheck  

[11888] INFO   Nov-05 05:11:45,210: Continuing previous session  
[11888] INFO   Nov-05 05:11:45,242:     Server:   https://someurl.tableauserver.com  
[11888] INFO   Nov-05 05:11:45,242:     Username: <username>  
[11888] INFO   Nov-05 05:11:45,260: Connecting to server...  
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:49,690: Authenticity token:   v2x4ltoI1rlcNYP875pO6ciYhWH8P3Vs7W15PMdWrWo=
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:49,113: upload options: {}  
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:50,661: /manual/file_uploads/create.xml  
[11888] DEBUG  Nov-05 05:11:50,680: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">  

&lt;HTML>&lt;HEAD>&lt;TITLE>Length Required&lt;/TITLE>  

&lt;META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">&lt;/HEAD>  

&lt;BODY>&lt;h2>Length Required&lt;/h2>  

&lt;hr>&lt;p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.&lt;/p>  

&lt;/BODY>&lt;/HTML>  


[11888] FATAL  Nov-05 05:11:50,682: 411 "Length Required"
```

I think the reason for this issue is the data stream sent to the server should contain Content-Length value. But i am not sure how can i set it?

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Is it possible to publish the same workbook via Tableau Desktop without error? Also, does your Tableau Server use SSL?

Comment: what is -o --no-certcheck? -o is overwrite option.